# Why are my divs not lining up? plus extra padding on a couple of divs

Tags: css, html, dreamweaver

```
    <style type="text/css">
    #1 {
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        float: left;
        height: 144px;
        width: 238px;
        position: relative;
        top: 0px;
    }
    #2 {
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        float: left;
        height: 144px;
        width: 762px;
        position: relative;
        top: 0px;
    }
    #3 {
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        float: left;
        height: 7px;
        width: 1000px;
        position: relative;
        top: 0px;
    }

    #4 {
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        float: left;
        height: 37px;
        width: 363px;
        position: relative;
        top: 0px;
    }
    #5 {
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        float: left;
        height: 37px;
        width: 637px;
        position: relative;
        top: 0px;

    }
    #6 {
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        float: left;
        height: 10px;
        width: 1000px;
        position: relative;
        top: 0px;

    }
    #7 {
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        float: left;
        height: 351px;
        width: 41px;
        position: relative;
        top: 0px;
    }
    #8 {
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        float: left;
        height: 351px;
        width: 198px;
        position: relative;
        top: 0px;
    }

    #9 {
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        float: left;
        height: 351px;
        width: 715px;
        position: relative;
        top: 0px;
    }
    #10 {
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        float: left;
        height: 351px;
        width: 46px;
        position: relative;
        top: 0px;
    }
    #11 {
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        float: left;
        height: 33px;
        width: 1000px;
        position: relative;
        top: 0px;
    }

 (12,13,14,15to be continued...........)

    #slider_holder {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        height: 351px;
        width: 715px;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: absolute;
    }
    </style>

    <script src="script/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script/cycle-master/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#slider').cycle({
        fx:     'fade',
        speed:  'slow',
        next:   '#next',
        prev:   '#prev'
    });
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
    #wrapper {
        display: block;
        height: 351px;
        width: 715px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
    #container {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        height: 351px;
        width: 715px;
        overflow: auto;
    }
    #prev {
        background-image: url(images/arrow_left.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
        display: block;
        float: left;
        height: 351px;
        width: 95px;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 10;
    }
    #next {
        background-image: url(images/arrow_right.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
        display: block;
        float: right;
        height: 351px;
        width: 95px;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 10;
    }
    #slider {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        height: 351px;
        width: 715px;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: absolute;
        visibility: inherit;
    }

    </style>

    <body>
    <div id="shotcrete">
        <div id="1"><img src="images/1_01.png" width="238" height="144" alt=""/></div>
        <div id="2"><img src="images/1_02.png" width="762" height="144" alt=""/></div>
        <div id="3"><img src="images/1_03.png" width="1000" height="7" alt=""/></div>
        <div id="4"><img src="images/1_04.png" width="363" height="37" alt=""/></div>
        <div id="5"><img src="images/1_05.png" width="637" height="37" alt=""/></div>
        <div id="6"><img src="images/1_06.png" width="1000" height="10" alt=""/></div>
        <div id="7"><img src="images/1_07.png" width="41" height="351" alt=""/></div>
        <div id="8"><img src="images/1_08.png" width="198" height="351" alt=""/></div>
        <div id="9">
        <div id="slider_holder">
                <div id="wrapper">
                    <div id="container">
                        <div class="controller" id="prev"></div>
                            <div id="slider">
                            <img src="images/slider/1.png" width="715" height="351" alt="1"/>
                            <img src="images/slider/2.png" width="715" height="351" alt="2"/>
                            <img src="images/slider/3.png" width="715" height="351" alt="3"/>
                            <img src="images/slider/4.png" width="715" height="351" alt="4"/>
                            <img src="images/slider/5.png" width="715" height="351" alt="5"/>
                            <img src="images/slider/6.png" width="715" height="351" alt="6"/>
                            </div>
                        <div class="controller" id="next"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="10"><img src="images/1_10.png" width="46" height="351" alt=""/></div>
        <div id="11"><img src="images/1_11.png" width="1000" height="33" alt=""/></div>
        <div id="12"><img src="images/1_12.png" width="722" height="62" alt=""/></div>
        <div id="13"><img src="images/1_13.png" width="232" height="62" alt=""/></div>
        <div id="14"><img src="images/1_14.png" width="46" height="62" alt=""/></div>
        <div id="15"><img src="images/1_15.png" width="41" height="267" alt=""/></div>
        <div id="16"><img src="images/1_16.png" width="266" height="267" alt=""/></div>
        <div id="17"><img src="images/1_17.png" width="56" height="267" alt=""/></div>
        <div id="18"><img src="images/1_18.png" width="266" height="267" alt=""/></div>
        <div id="19"><img src="images/1_19.png" width="59" height="267" alt=""/></div>
        <div id="20"><img src="images/1_20.png" width="266" height="267" alt=""/></div>
        <div id="21"><img src="images/1_21.png" width="46" height="267" alt=""/></div>
        <div id="22"><img src="images/1_22.png" width="1000" height="35" alt=""/></div>
        <div id="23"><img src="images/1_23.png" width="1000" height="104" alt=""/></div>
    </div>


I am trying to get my divs to line up side by side.  I used the same parameters that rendered me a successful project previously, however I must be missing something for it to work properly.

There seems to be two things going on.  Primarily there is a break between every div, resulting in each div stacking on top of each other and not lining up side by side.

The second, there seems to be extra padding on Div 3 and Div 6.

I looked throw the KB and saw that removing any padding or adding -padding helps. I tried to add but this did not fix the issue.

Also, There seems to be a break in my code but I can not seem to find where it is.  In Dreamweaver, code displays inline, however in live view and in any browser, my code breaks at Div Id 8.
```

What I would like the code to do is line up all my divs sideways into a container div centered in the middle of the page with no padding 1000px x 1050 px.

I have inspected each element mentioned meticulously but alas am overlooking something.

thanks in advanced.

this is what the final product should look like.
[what i should look like](http://www.sharklystudios.com/images/layout.png)

Comment: where is your inline block command, the divs need to be inline blocks to show it side by side.

Comment: I added the inline block command, this made no difference in the results.